# What is Javascript Input regex for Accepting integers and double accepting comma as decimal seperator

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I am creating an app with React JS. I have input field for money. I want to accept only integers and double values with comma. I need a regex for that purpose.
For instance,

1 is ok
2,5 is ok
20,3 is ok
2.5 not ok.
35.65 not ok

Can anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try  `/^(?!\,)[\d\,]+(?<!\,)$/`

**Where:**

`^` starts at the beginning of the string

`(?!\,)` ensures that it will not match
`,` literally at the begging (***Negative Lookahead***)

`\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`\,` matches the character `,` literally

`+` matches between one and unlimited times

`(?<!\,)` ensure that the Regex will not match the character `,` literally at the end (***Negative Lookbehind***)

`$` asserts position at the end of the string

```js
var patt = /^(?!\,)[\d\,]+(?<!\,)$/;
console.log(patt.test('1'));
console.log(patt.test('2,5'));
console.log(patt.test('20,3'));
console.log(patt.test('2.5'));
console.log(patt.test('35.65'));

//The following shows no starting or trailing comma are allowed
console.log(patt.test(',123'));
console.log(patt.test('123,'));
```

Comment: Not sure if *",123" or "123," or ",,,,,"* is accepted, must not be. this may work /^(\d,\d)+$/

Comment: @AZ_, didn't notice that....updated the answer.....thanks:)